# execute functions in specific order

Tags: go

I have the following function

```
func (c *Connection) ConnectVpn() error {

    cmd := exec.Command(c.Command, c.Args...)

    var password bytes.Buffer
    password.WriteString(os.Getenv("PASSWORD"))

    cmd.Stdin = &password
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return err

}
```

This function call the `openconnect` binary and connects in a private vpn to be able to reach a specific server (it works fine).

The problem is that when I call `cmd.Start()` it creates a thread and allows me to execute the another function named `checkCertificate()` but then this function is called before the vpn connects so it fails.
When I try to let the VPN connects and use `cmd.RUN()` this process do not run on background so the process never finish and it never tells to `cmd.Wait()` it finished because it shouldn't finish.

```
days, err := domain.CheckCertificate()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
```

I have tried to use channels to try to sync the results between them but when I do this the `checkCertificate()` function keeps being executed before the VPN executes and I can't reach the server I need.

Any idea in how I could let the `ConnectVPN()` function be running on foreground and even so send some signal to my other function to say vpn is connected now, please run?

I have tried to send the `openconnect` to background with `cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGTSTP)` but when I bring it back it breaks the main function.

Comment: I imagine you can look for a particular message in openconnect's output, but that is somewhat brittle (version differences and language settings can break this). The typical solution is to retry the certificate check a few times, possibly with exponential backoff.

Comment: @Peter you mean to put some sort of loop to keep retrying ?
well it would be an option but should have a more elegant way to do this, maybe I am not using the channels correctly and should have a way to sync this.

Comment: Unless OpenConnect has a way to know when the connection is established, you need to  either wait and retry, or poll using something like [`net.Interfaces()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Interfaces) until the interface you expect appears.

Comment: Have you considered/tried using the `--background` option with `OpenConnect`? If the command goes to background and returns only *after* it successfuly connects, then you could possibly invoke it, in Go, with `cmd.Run()` and when that returns without an error you should be able to proceed to check the certificate, no?

Comment: @mkopriva, Yes I am using the background option but even so this is not enough to sync when the process goes to background, the certCertificate() function is triggered before the connection is established.
I will add a function to check if this is connected as the others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the function to check if this is connected as was suggested before.
Now it only triggers the other functions if this VPN is connected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gitlabCertCheck/request"
    "gitlabCertCheck/teams"
    "gitlabCertCheck/vpn"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func checker() {
    client := http.Client{}
    _, err := client.Get(os.Getenv("HTTPS_HOST"))
    if err != nil {
        checker()
    }
    return
}

func main() {

    args := []string{"--user", os.Getenv("USERNAME"), "--authgroup", "default", "--background",os.Getenv("VPN_SERVER")}
    conn := vpn.NewConnection("openconnect", args)
    err := conn.ConnectVpn()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    checker()

        client := request.Request{}

        domain := client.NewRequest(os.Getenv("HOST"), os.Getenv("PORT"))
        days, err := domain.CheckCertificate()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        card := teams.Card{}
        card.CustomCard.Title = "Certificate Alert"
        card.CustomCard.Text = "Certificate will expire in " + strconv.Itoa(days) + " days"
        card.NewCard(card.CustomCard)
        err = card.SendMessageCard(os.Getenv("TEAMS_WEBHOOK"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: I suggest you to use this package https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp?utm_source=godoc to implement the retry with backoff. Otherwise, instead of recursive calls, use an outer for loop and check for errors to determine when to break.

Comment: @mh-cbon Thank you for the suggestion, will implement the requests using the library you suggested.